# What are some less ambiguous words for "choice," "decision," "option," etc.?

Tags: meaning, nouns, word-usage, ambiguity

1)  You come to a fork in the road.

You need to make a *choice* between going left or right.  You face a *decision* between the left path and the right path.  You have the *option* to advance in either direction.

2)  You go right.

Right was your *choice*.  Right was your *decision*.  Right was the *option* you selected.

In the case of 2), each of the three words is used to denote an alternative.  Right is a choice, a decision, an option, or an alternative.  In the case of 1), each word is used to denote a set of competing alternatives.  "Left or right?" is a choice to be made, a decision to be faced, an option of which way to go, or a set of competing alternatives.

All three of these words seem to be ambiguous between 1) and 2) (and of course, there's nothing special about the fork in the road example; this is a general problem that can make it difficult to use these words effectively in some contexts).  What I would like to ask for are two separate lists of a few words that are uniquely appropriate for 1), and a few other words that are uniquely appropriate for 2).  Thus far it seems *alternative* and *selection* might work uniquely for 2), but I've come up with nothing at all uniquely applicable to 1).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I think the starting point for this question is to explain *your* distinction between the two. E.g. the first is something that exists independently from you, and the second is completely dependent on you. Is that what you're trying to express? If so, *option* vs *decision* seems appropriate.

Comment: Decision is different:  you can have multiple choices, meaning multiple options, and you can say that your choice was to go left.  But there is only ever one decision:  the left and right paths are options, but only the one you go down can be referred to as your decision.

Comment: What about the "choosing" or "making a choice" for the first one?

Answer (score 0):

If neither fork in the road would lead you to a happy place, [**dilemma**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dilemma?s=t) would work for 1) (a set of competing alternatives):

noun
1.  a situation requiring a choice between equally undesirable alternatives.
 (from *Dictionary.com*)

You face a dilemma between [taking] the left path and the right path.

And for 2) (the alternative chosen to **resolve** the dilemma), there’s [**resolution**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/resolution):

Noun  …
3. something resolved or determined; decision
(from *Collins Dictionary*)

[Turning] Right was your [selected] resolution.

Answer (score 0):

1) You come to a fork in the road.

> You have the ***possibility*** to advance in either direction.

2) You go right.

> Right was your ***chosen*** path.

*Possibility* cannot be used in (2) and *chosen* cannot be used in (1).

Answer (score 0):

I really like this question.

I see four distinct meanings here instead of two, namely: (1) an act or instance of choosing, (2) a thing that can be chosen, (3) the set of things that can be chosen among, and (4) a thing that has been chosen.

In these terms, I think you’re looking for a noun that means 1 but cannot mean 2 and cannot mean 4, and you’re also looking for a noun that means 2 or 4 but cannot mean 1.

Unfortunately, I can’t find anything that fits the bill:

Choice

- 1 - “He faced a choice of snowball flavor.”
- 2 - “He had over 20 choices for flavor.”
- 3 - “He marveled at the broad choice.”
- 4 - “His choice was spearmint.”

Decision

- 1 - “It was his decision what flavor to get.”
- 4 - “His decision was cherry.”

Option

- 1 - “He faced the option of a lump sum or an annuity.”
- 2 - “There were three options on the ballot.”
- 4 - “He was served the vegetarian option.”

Alternative

- 1 - “She faced the alternative of speaking up or staying quiet.”
- 2 - “Several alternatives occurred to her.”

Selection

- 1 - “Selection took three months because there were so many applicants.”
- 2 - “There were several selections available.”
- 3 - “There was a wide selection at the potluck.”
- 4 - “The user’s selection was shown in the lower left.”

Resolution

- 1 - Resolution of the dilemma dragged on for months.
- 4 - His resolution to run every day was forgotten by the end of January.

Possibility

- 2 - “Several possibilities were presented to the board.”
- 3 - “Her future was full of possibility.”

As a practical matter, if you want to avoid this ambiguity, I suggest using choice-related verbs instead of abstract nouns. On-point verbs combined with concrete nouns are often stylistically better than abstract nouns anyway. For example:

- “Bob must decided on a color.” (Compare: “Bob must make a decision among the color possibilities.”)
- “You can choose a three-year or five-year term.” (Compare: “Your choice is between three-year or five-year alternatives.”)
- “He always opts for a flavor he hasn’t tried.” (Compare: “His choice is always a flavor option he hasn’t tried.”)
- “The board selected the offer with the largest cash component.” (Compare: “The board’s selection was the alternative with the largest cash component.”)